# Unable to delete php extension

Tags: php

So I have an extension in PHP's folder which I want to be deleted, however, it throws this error.

```
A:extensions as$ ls
no-debug-non-zts-20121212   no-debug-non-zts-20131226
A:extensions as$ rm -rf no-debug-non-zts-20121212
rm: no-debug-non-zts-20121212: Operation not permitted
A:extensions as$ ls -lOe
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  restricted  68 Dec  7  2016 no-debug-non-zts-20121212
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel  restricted 170 Nov 16 23:49 no-debug-non-zts-20131226
```

How can I delete these both folders under /extensions? I'm running on a Macbook pro.

Comment: sudo it, its owned by root. `sudo rm -rf no-debug-non-zts-20121212`

Answer (score 0):

Those folders are owned by `root`. You will need to add `sudo` to your `rm` command.

`sudo` allows you to run programs with the security privileges of another user, by default the superuser, or root in this case.

`sudo rm -rf no-debug-non-zts-20121212 no-debug-non-zts-20131226`